# SQLite Vs. File IO while reading a dictionary

Tags: android, sqlite, io

I am creating an application where I have a dictionary and the user enters a word and the app will compare the word to words from the dictionary. should I use a text file or a table in the database to store the dictionary words?

Comment: How many words are you planning to have? I think that a database would be faster in most cases, and would definitely be faster if you're reading the file line by line.

Comment: joshhendo is correct, but for small sizes, it might be the difference between 0.002 seconds and 0.01 seconds. No one would ever know.

Answer (score 1):

Short version of the story:

- If you are not expecting to have more than, say, 1,000-10,000 words, a flat file should be fine and so fast you'll never notice.
- The benefit of SQLite is that it's got some optimizations. If the data were more complicated, or if you wanted to be able to look up by other info like "words that were entered on a Tuesday that have more than 10 words in their definition" then that would be a compelling argument to use it.

I hope that helps!